# What is the purpose of the complex features behind the numberplate on this Jaguar F-Type?

Tags: license-plates

What is the purpose of the complex cut-outs on the mounting point for the rear (and front, in other pictures of the same vehicle) numberplates, on this Jaguar F-Type?

Do any other models come with this type of feature, or is it particular to this model? I don't recall seeing many cars with their plates removed.

[image: Exposed plate mounting showing small convoluted features]

Comment: This almost looks like they used that material to cut out several small parts used in other places, and then used the larger "scrap" to become the plate holder.  The cutouts just seem too random to serve any real purpose.

Comment: While the current top answer answer is true, I definitely think @JPhi1618 is correct in his statement for this particular vehicle

Answer (score 2):

It is quite common to see such cutouts on the backs of licence plate frames.

The actual pattern may differ, but the purpose for the cutouts is to accommodate mounting points of different dimensions.

As a side, I don't think this is something manufacturer-specific; more often than not dealerships have to source the plate frames to accommodate the licence plate dimensions that are standard to their region.

[image: AutoZone]

[image: eBay]